# Creating several weight tensors for each object in Multi-Object Tracking (MOT) using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow V1.10.0 and developing a Multi-Object Tracker based on MDNet. I need to assign a separate weight matrix for each detected object for the fully connected layers in order to get different embedding for each object during online training. I am using this tf.map_fn in order to generate a higher-order weight tensor (n_objects, flattened layer, hidden_units),

'''

```
    def dense_fc4(n_objects):
        initializer = lambda: tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()(shape=(1024, 512))
        return tf.Variable(initial_value=initializer, name='fc4/kernel',
                           shape=(n_objects.shape[0], 1024, 512))


    W4 = tf.map_fn(dense_fc4, samples_flat)
    b4 = tf.get_variable('fc4/bias', shape=512, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(samples_flat, W4), b4)
    fc4 = tf.nn.relu(fc4)
```

'''

However during execution when I run the session for W4 I get a weight matrix but all having the same values. Any help?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround, I was able to generate the multiple kernels outside the graph in a for loop and then giving it to the graph:

```
w6 = []
for n_obj in range(pos_data.shape[0]):
    w6.append(tf.get_variable("fc6/kernel-" + str(n_obj), shape=(512, 2),
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()))

print("modeling fc6 branches...")
prob, train_op, accuracy, loss, pred, initialize_vars, y, fc6 = build_branches(fc5, w6)

def build_branches(fc5, w6):
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, None])

    b6 = tf.get_variable('fc6/bias', shape=2, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    fc6 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc5, w6), b6)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,
                                                                         logits=fc6))

    train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="fc6")

    with tf.variable_scope("",  reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, name='adam')
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=train_vars)

        initialize_vars = train_vars
        initialize_vars += [optimizer.get_slot(var, name)
                            for name in optimizer.get_slot_names()
                            for var in train_vars]
        if isinstance(optimizer, tf.train.AdamOptimizer):
            initialize_vars += optimizer._get_beta_accumulators()

    prob = tf.nn.softmax(fc6)
    pred = tf.argmax(prob, 2)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(pred, y)

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    return prob, train_op, accuracy, loss, pred, initialize_vars, y, fc6
```

[image: Graph]